# Procedural graphics for learning Python

Tags: python

Can anyone recommend a good compact Python graphics library (with tutorials) which is suitable for motivating stronger students in an introductory programming course? I mean library for creating images, not image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you call "images".
If graphs may also be called "images", give matplotlib an eye.
It also displays pictures.
And there is a huge sample library.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This seems interesting -- i'll recommend this to students interested in math.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there aren't any libraries that have been written only for *creating images*. Most of the examples I have seen around are using some kind of image processing library (like [PiL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) and rely on [clever](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html) [algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)[rithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

Besides, procedural generation of various data structures can be used in variety of scenarios besides generating images/textures.

You can find a big list of algorithms from [Procedural Content Generation Wiki](http://pcg.wikidot.com/category-pcg-algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

The very basic 'picture drawing' facilities are provided by the [turtle](http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html) module from the standard Python library. It is not the kind of interface used normally for computer graphics, though.

Comment: turtle will be exploited, for sure. I was just thinking of something more..., serious, i guess.